# Slice numpy ndarry of arbitrary dimension to 1d array given a list of indices

Tags: python, numpy, slice, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I have a numpy ndarray `arr` and also `indices`, a list of indices specifying a particular entry.  For concreteness let's take:

```
arr = np.arange(2*3*4).reshape((2,3,4))
indices= [1,0,3]
```

I have code to take 1d slices through `arr` observing all but one index `n`:

```
arr[:, indices[1], indices[2]]  # n = 0
arr[indices[0], :, indices[2]]  # n = 1
arr[indices[0], indices[1], :]  # n = 2
```

I would like to change my code to loop over `n` and support an `arr` of arbitrary dimension.

I've had a look at the [indexing routines](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.indexing.html) entry in the documentation and found information about `slice()` and `np.s_()`. I was able to hack together something that works like what I want:

```
def make_custom_slice(n, indices):
    s = list()
    for i, idx in enumerate(indices):
        if i == n:
            s.append(slice(None))
        else:
            s.append(slice(idx, idx+1))
    return tuple(s)


for n in range(arr.ndim):
    np.squeeze(arr[make_custom_slice(n, indices)])
```

Where `np.squeeze` is used to remove the axes of length 1.  Without this, the array this produced has shape `(arr.shape[n],1,1,...)` rather than `(arr.shape[n],)`.

Is there a more idiomatic way to accomplish this task?

Comment: "Is there a more idiomatic way to accomplish this task?" Idiomatic ways to accomplish the task with Numpy generally involve *not writing loops*.

Comment: I agree with this.  The improvements I posted below remove the loop in the function that builds the slice object.  I'm not sure if the function can be vectorized in n to remove the loop where it is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some improvements to the solution above (there may still be a one-liner or a more performant solution):

```
def make_custom_slice(n, indices):
    s = indices.copy()
    s[n] = slice(None)
    return tuple(s)


for n in range(arr.ndim):
    print(arr[make_custom_slice(n, indices)])
```

An integer value `idx` can be used to replace the slice object `slice(idx, idx+1)`. Because most indices are copied over directly, start with a copy of indices rather than building the list from scratch.

When built in this way, the result of `arr[make_custom_slice(n, indices)` has the expected dimension and `np.squeeze` is unnecessary.